# Counting rows in SQL with multiple AND & OR statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a database by a date range in which they were created and by if they are one of several zip codes.  Semantically what I'm trying to say is count all the complaints from these zip codes during this period of time.  My query looks like this,

`select COUNT(*) 
  from complaints 
    where created_date::date >= '2013-10-03' 
      AND created_date::date <= '2014-05-31' 
        AND incident_zip = 11209
          OR incident_zip = 11201
            OR incident_zip = 11202;`

I can't seem to get the query to run without the `OR` statement making the `AND` statements meaningless.  Could someone explain how to group it so the `OR` statement only affects the incident_zip column and not the created_date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there's no need for multiple clauses containing `incident_zip`. Instead, group them together using an `IN` clause:

```
select COUNT(*)
from complaints
where created_date::date >= '2013-10-03'
  AND created_date::date <= '2014-05-31'
  AND incident_zip IN (11209, 11201, 11202);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets () to group the ORs:

```
select COUNT(*) from complaints
where created_date::date >= '2013-10-03' AND created_date::date <= '2014-05-31'
AND (incident_zip = 11209 OR incident_zip = 11201 OR incident_zip = 11202);
```

Depending on your SQL language you might be able to write:

```
select COUNT(*) from complaints
where created_date::date BETWEEN '2013-10-03' AND '2014-05-31'
AND incident_zip IN (11209, 11201, 11202);
```